# How to kill while loop?

Tags: python

For example, I have code:

```
while (1):
    bla-bla-bal
    time.sleep(10)
```

How to change this code, for kill this loop  ( NOT KILL -9 ) or Keyboard interrrupt ( Ctrl-C ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Use break or change the boolean  variable in while

```
while True:
    doit
    if something:
        break
```

alternatively:

```
i_go = True
while i_go:
    doit
    if something:
        i_go = False
```

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a condition that exists which the loop no longer needs to be performed.  Depending on what it is (it's a bit too tough to tell from the code that's up now), you can enter a break statement.

Example:

```
while True:
    # doing stuff
    if end_condition:
        break # Valid ending condition
```

Comment: Indeed, using break allows you to, well, break out of a loop. Now, don't forget that you can also use `while not end_condition: do stuff()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (1):
    bla-bla-bal
    time.sleep(10)
```

I think you mean that Ctrl+C is not working during `time.sleep(10)`.

If so, split it into 1 second chunks:

```
while (1):
    bla-bla-bal
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
```